# Transform Table by Date into a New From-To Table

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

We have a infrastructure system on railsways. All components have a Valid_From and Valid_To date. For a given project we need to join up to 8 tables, and each of the layers can have different periods. So the only fast way to het the right combination of each layer was to perform this with a date table.
Works fine and correct.
But now I'm having as example such a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [ods_tr_amelie].[INES_DATA_PREP_INES_ROUTING_OK]
(
    [MAP_DATE] [DATE] NULL,
    [FROM_ID_PK] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [FROM_INES_KPO] [INT] NULL,
    [TO_ID_PK] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [ROUT_MAX_SPEED] [INT] NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [MAP_DATE] ),
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
```

Now I would like to transform this back to a VALID_FROM - VALID_TO table. But ... As this is running on a Azure SQL Datawarehouse, I can't use cursors, must be done in normal Selects with references to itself in needed.

The key on what the period should be created is FROM_ID_PK, FROM_INES_KPO, TO_ID_PK and ROUT_MAX_SPEED.

A MIN(MAP_DATE) and MAX(MAP_DATE) is not correct as shown in the  simplified data sample below.

```
MAP_DATE   SYMBOLIC_KEY
01/01/2020 VALUE_X
01/02/2020 VALUE_Y
01/03/2020 VALUE_X
01/04/2020 VALUE_X
```

MIN_MAX Would Create

```
SYMBOLIC_KEY VALID_FROM VALID_TO
VALUE_X      01/01/2020 01/04/2020
VALUE_Y      01/02/2020 01/02/2020
```

And the wanted result would be

```
SYMBOLIC_KEY VALID_FROM VALID_TO
VALUE_X      01/01/2020 01/01/2020
VALUE_Y      01/02/2020 01/02/2020
VALUE_X      01/03/2020 01/04/2020
```

Any suggestion would be great ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select symbolic_value, min(map_date), max(map_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by map_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by symbolic_value order by map_date) as seqnum_1
      from INES_DATA_PREP_INES_ROUTING_OK t
     ) t
group by symbolic_value, (seqnum - seqnum_1);
```

Note:  Your data doesn't have gaps in the dates.  This version ignores gaps.  If you want them to create separate groups, then:

```
select symbolic_value, min(map_date), max(map_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by map_date) as seqnum
      from INES_DATA_PREP_INES_ROUTING_OK t
     ) t
group by symbolic_value, datediff(day, - seqnum, map_date);
```